# About us section picture won't show

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have an image showing in the about us section on my website however it doesn't appear, it is there because if I drag the image on the site you can see the thumbnail of it.

I have tried moving the picture to different places in my folder, tried messing around with some css to see if that is the issue but I can't seem to find the fix

HTML

```
        <section id="about">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="section-header">
                    <h2>About Us</h2>
                </div>

                <center>

                    <img src="img/about%20us.jpg">
                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <h3>The Off Beats are a young punk band based in lichfield. Formed at college in late 2017, we love putting on high energy performances. We all love different styles of music so the songs we write have something for everybody. Our main influence is punk music. We started to form fully in 2018 creating a sound of our own and playing a few local gigs. This is where we first started to realise that we have a distinctive style.</h3>

                </center>
            </div>
        </section>
```

CSS

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# About Section
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

#about {
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    padding: 60px 0 40px 0;
}

#about:before {
    content: "";
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#about h2 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #112363;
}

#about h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: black;
}

#about p {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: green;
}
```

I expect the image to be showing in the about us section

Video to show the issue
https://youtu.be/uwxjTKFTx0Y

Comment: take a look at the z-index property

Comment: the `center` tag has been deprecated in `HTML5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `before` pseudo element which is set to cover the entire section it is positioned against. Try removing this pseudo-declaration entirely first, and see is that solves the problem (it should).

```
#about {
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    padding: 60px 0 40px 0;
}

/* ——- remove this 
#about:before {
    content: "";
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
*/
```

It looks like you are just trying to add a full white overlay to the section. If that’s the case, just add it as an individual element inside the `#about` section and give the image a higher `z-index`, like so:

```
<section id=“about”>
    <div class=“overlay”>
    <img src=“...”>
</section>

.overlay {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   z-index: 25;
}

img {
   z-index: 50;
}
```